# HTTP POST size issue

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I've developed a module with Spring framework and for the view i've used some Spring JSTL tags like `<form:hidden>`

I have a table on the jsp which i store using an Arraylist.

Now when i do some other action, i have to maintain the Table and since we are not using AJAX(Client doesnt wants it!!) , what i've done is that i've put all the list elements one by one into `<form:hidden>`.Now everytime i do a select for one of the elements of the list, i have to maintain the list and that is taken care off via the  tag.

But when i go on selecting multiple records one by one, i've noticed(    System.out.println("Request Size : " + request.getContentLength())), the size increases everytime and when it reaches 3MB, the system crashes. Is there any way i can increase the size of the POST method, in eclipse or websphere? or is there any way i can clear the request so that the size doesnt increase? please help.

Comment: What kind of exception do you get? 
Do you need to increase Heap memory with the -Xmx JVM param?

Comment: First: why are you using post, when you are clearly not posting anything, and are rather getting information?  Second: why does having made previous queries increase the request size?

Comment: hi @Crollster , The DTO which i use, gets empty, i.e. all the elements are made null after a size of 3MB and hence i get a null pointer exception for the same.

Comment: hi @bdares , i'm using a POST since, i'm not getting new values, but we have to use the selected list record, make a DB call to retrieve any related data to the list and to maintain the list records.

Comment: The request size might be increasing, since i've put the entire list elements in the     <form:hidden> tag as      <form:hidden path="list(0).element1"/>

Comment: why do you have to maintain the list?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using form:hidden to submit all the array values, maybe you could use form:hidden to submit only the index of the elements in the array

Comment: Hi All, actually the problem was, there were two variables declared twice as <form:hidden>, after removal of one, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain the state at the server side, possible in HTTPSession. Whenever, the state changes on the page and has to be committed, only the state changes should be POSTed back to the server. Sending 3 MB worth of data in request will not scale.